# Prevent facebook from suggesting images when sharing a link

Tags: facebook, share

When I share a link(page) from my application, facebook suggests some images, description etc. Is it possible to disable this, especially images.

Comment: i'm not sure how to disable links. But you can disable thumbnail images by check the "No Thumbnail" checkbox.

Comment: @Ivan That would be for the person sharing the link, not the person who is developing the application.

Comment: @9muses looks like i have mix it with something else. i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the following options in your HTML-header.

```
<meta name="description" content="My share text" />
<link rel=”image_src“ href=”my-image.png” />
```

Then that information will be caught by Facebook and used when you share. Please note though that Facebook caches your site so it will be a few days until you notice any difference on pages that have been shared before. On non-shared pages it will work from the beginning.

Comment: How does this stop an image from being shared?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable images by selecting the "No Thumbnail" link before posting.